# Using OWIN SelfHost with Facebook Authentication

Tags: c#, facebook-authentication, self-hosting, owin

I'm using OWIN to self host a WebApi, and I've been looking at the newest SPA template included in VS 2013 RC as a guide. I have a Startup.Configure method which looks like this (copied from SPA as much as possible):

```cs
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
    config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(Startup.OAuthOptions.AuthenticationType));

    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    app.UseWebApi(config);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(CookieOptions);

    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(ExternalCookieAuthenticationType);

    app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions, ExternalOAuthAuthenticationType);

    app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
        appId: "123456",           // obviously changed for this post
        appSecret: "deadbeef");    // obviously changed for this post
}
```

Which gets invoked in my command-line app like so:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(port: 1234)) { /* ... */ }
}
```

I also have an AccountController straight out of the SPA template, yet when I manually "curl" the url `http://localhost:1234/api/Account/ExternalLogins?returnUrl=%2F&generateState=true` I get an empty array. What am I missing?

Note: if you're familiar with the ExternalLogins endpoint, it eventually calls `Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalAuthenticationTypes()`, which in my case returns nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OWIN middleware registration sequence matters here. The right order is to register web api after all authentication middleware. The following code should work:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
    config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(Startup.OAuthOptions.AuthenticationType));

    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(CookieOptions);

    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(ExternalCookieAuthenticationType);

    app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions, ExternalOAuthAuthenticationType);

    app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
        appId: "123456",           // obviously changed for this post
        appSecret: "deadbeef");    // obviously changed for this post


    app.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

BTW, I just wrote a blog to explain the security features in SPA template. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/09/20/understanding-security-features-in-spa-template.aspx

Comment: Very astute, that's exactly what it was. I must say, that's a rather unexpected constraint (that the order matters). Is that a design flaw which potentially needs to be addressed? I'll gladly raise an issue in the CodePlex project if you think so.